# Can't Show row (cell values) in jqGrid when is objects (in cell) nos array of values

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

When I bind my jqgrid with follow json from server, my lines are redered but without cell text, for each cell I use a object instead a array of values, when I use the method to addRowGrid directly all works fine:

```
{"total":1,"records":2,"page":1,"rows":[{"id":14,"cell":{"Edital":{"OpcaoDesclassificacaoRegraDezPorcento":false,"DataInclusaoEdital":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","NumeroEdital":"99902/2012","DescricaoObjeto":"BURGO","DataInicioFase":"2012-08-02T14:50:00","DataHoraUltimaAlteracao":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","InformacaoAtributoPadrao":false,"Lotes":[],"EditalConvidados":[],"EditalAdendos":[],"EditalAnexos":[],"MembrosEquipe":[],"Interessados":[],"Objetivo":"","NomeModalidade":"","NomeModalidaCompleta":"","NomeSituacao":"","NomeOrgaoPromotor":"","NomeUnidadeCompradora":"","ChaveIdentificacaoDocumento":"DOCUMENTO_EDITAL","VenceMenorOferta":false,"Versao":0,"Chave":8005},"Modalidade":{"Descricao":"Pregão","Chave":1},"TipoLicitacao":{"Descricao":"Pública","SiglaSistemaBbmnet":"LIC","Chave":1},"TipoCotacao":{"Descricao":"Menor Preço","Chave":1},"OrgaoPromotor":{"NomeResumido":"CESAT OrgPub","IsAtivo":false,"Chave":1162},"EtapaLote":{"Descricao":"Não iniciado","Chave":1},"SituacaoLote":{"Descricao":"Em Andamento","Chave":1},"TipoTermino":{"IsRandomico":true,"Chave":1},"Lote":{"QuantidadeCasaDecimal":0,"DataHoraAlteracao":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","OfertasVencedoras":[],"Ofertas":[],"ItensLote":[],"LoteAdendos":[],"NumeroLote":1,"ValorTotalItensLote":0.0,"NumeroRodada":1,"Eventos":[],"DescricaoProduto":"","SomaPrecoProdutos":0.0,"DescricaoSituacaoLote":"","EditalLoteFormatado":"","DescricaoTipoLicitacao":"","DescricaoModalidade":"","NomeOrgaoPromotor":"","DataHoraInicio":"","Objeto":"","Versao":0,"OfertasMPEPP":[],"QuantidadeOfertasAtivas":0,"Chave":8029},"LoteItem":{"QuantidadeProduto":100.00000,"UnidadeProduto":{"DataInclusao":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Chave":0.0},"PrecoProduto":0.0,"PrecoProdutoAtual":0.0,"DataHoraAlteracao":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Numero":0,"CodigoDescricaoProduto":"","PrecoProdutoFormatado":"0,00","Ofertas":[],"Chave":8283},"CodigoUnidade":"Unidade","TempoDecorrido":0,"PrecoReferencia":50000.0000000000000,"PercentualVariacao":0.00,"DataHoraUltimaAlteracao":"2012-08-02T14:33:22","Estado":{"Chave":"AC"},"DivulgacaoPreco":false,"DataHoraUltimoInicio":"2012-08-02T14:50:00","QuantidadeInteressado":0.00000,"DescricaoModalidade":"Pregão Pública Menor Preço","PrecoReferenciaExibicao":50000.0000000000000,"PercentualVariacaoExibicao":0.00,"TempoDecorridoExibicao":1197202,"QuantidadeProdutoExibicao":"100,00000Unidade","SituacaoExibicao":"Não iniciado/Em Andamento","Legendas":[4],"MelhorLanceExibicao":0.0,"Chave":14}},{"id":15,"cell":{"Edital":{"OpcaoDesclassificacaoRegraDezPorcento":false,"DataInclusaoEdital":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","NumeroEdital":"99902/2012","DescricaoObjeto":"BURGO","DataInicioFase":"2012-08-02T14:50:00","DataHoraUltimaAlteracao":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","InformacaoAtributoPadrao":false,"Lotes":[],"EditalConvidados":[],"EditalAdendos":[],"EditalAnexos":[],"MembrosEquipe":[],"Interessados":[],"Objetivo":"","NomeModalidade":"","NomeModalidaCompleta":"","NomeSituacao":"","NomeOrgaoPromotor":"","NomeUnidadeCompradora":"","ChaveIdentificacaoDocumento":"DOCUMENTO_EDITAL","VenceMenorOferta":false,"Versao":0,"Chave":8005},"Modalidade":{"Descricao":"Pregão","Chave":1},"TipoLicitacao":{"Descricao":"Pública","SiglaSistemaBbmnet":"LIC","Chave":1},"TipoCotacao":{"Descricao":"Menor Preço","Chave":1},"OrgaoPromotor":{"NomeResumido":"CESAT OrgPub","IsAtivo":false,"Chave":1162},"EtapaLote":{"Descricao":"Não iniciado","Chave":1},"SituacaoLote":{"Descricao":"Em Andamento","Chave":1},"TipoTermino":{"IsRandomico":true,"Chave":1},"Lote":{"QuantidadeCasaDecimal":0,"DataHoraAlteracao":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","OfertasVencedoras":[],"Ofertas":[],"ItensLote":[],"LoteAdendos":[],"NumeroLote":2,"ValorTotalItensLote":0.0,"NumeroRodada":1,"Eventos":[],"DescricaoProduto":"","SomaPrecoProdutos":0.0,"DescricaoSituacaoLote":"","EditalLoteFormatado":"","DescricaoTipoLicitacao":"","DescricaoModalidade":"","NomeOrgaoPromotor":"","DataHoraInicio":"","Objeto":"","Versao":0,"OfertasMPEPP":[],"QuantidadeOfertasAtivas":0,"Chave":8030},"LoteItem":{"QuantidadeProduto":50.00000,"UnidadeProduto":{"DataInclusao":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Chave":0.0},"PrecoProduto":0.0,"PrecoProdutoAtual":0.0,"DataHoraAlteracao":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Numero":0,"CodigoDescricaoProduto":"","PrecoProdutoFormatado":"0,00","Ofertas":[],"Chave":8284},"CodigoUnidade":"Caixa","TempoDecorrido":0,"PrecoReferencia":5000.0000000000000,"PercentualVariacao":0.00,"DataHoraUltimaAlteracao":"2012-08-02T14:33:22","Estado":{"Chave":"AC"},"DivulgacaoPreco":false,"DataHoraUltimoInicio":"2012-08-02T14:50:00","QuantidadeInteressado":0.00000,"DescricaoModalidade":"Pregão Pública Menor Preço","PrecoReferenciaExibicao":5000.0000000000000,"PercentualVariacaoExibicao":0.00,"TempoDecorridoExibicao":1197202,"QuantidadeProdutoExibicao":"50,00000Caixa","SituacaoExibicao":"Não iniciado/Em Andamento","Legendas":[4],"MelhorLanceExibicao":0.0,"Chave":15}}]}
```

Follow my code:

```
$("#gridRelacaoLote").jqGrid({
        url: '<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Handlers/RelacaoLoteHandler.ashx") %>',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['ID', 'Situacao Exibição', 'Cod. Unidade', 'Modalidade'],
        colModel: [{ name: 'Chave', index: 'Chave', width: 20, align: 'right', editable: false, hidden: true },
                   { name: 'SituacaoExibicao', index: 'SituacaoExibicao', width: 200, editable: false },
                   { name: 'CodigoUnidade', index: 'CodigoUnidade', width: 80, editable: false, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'DescricaoModalidade', index: 'DescricaoModalidade', width: 80, editable: false, align: 'left' }
                      ],
            pager: $('#paginadorRelacaoLote'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 15, 20, 25],
            sortname: 'Chave',
            sortorder: 'asc',
            viewrecords: true,
            autowidth: true,
            height: 160,
            recordtext: "Lotes de {0} até {1} / {2}",
            emptyrecords: "Nenhum lote encontrado.",
            loadtext: "Aguarde, carregando dados...",
            pgtext: "Página {0} de {1}",
            caption: "Lotes", 
            beforeProcessing: function(data) {

            }            
        });
```

[image: Grid with problem]

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem,

in jqGrid options put:

```
jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                id: "Chave"
            }
```

And changed json format removing cell property from json:

```
{"total":1,"records":2,"page":1,"rows":[{"**Edital":{"OpcaoDesclassificacaoRegraDezPorcento":false,"DataInclusaoEdital":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","NumeroEdital":"99902/2012","DescricaoObjeto":"BURGO","DataInicioFase":"2012-08-02T14:50:00","DataHoraUltimaAlteracao":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","InformacaoAtributoPadrao":false,"Lotes":[],"EditalConvidados":[],"EditalAdendos":[],"EditalAnexos":[],"MembrosEquipe":[],"Interessados":[],"Objetivo":"","NomeModalidade":"","NomeModalidaCompleta":"","NomeSituacao":"","NomeOrgaoPromotor":"","NomeUnidadeCompradora":"","ChaveIdentificacaoDocumento":"DOCUMENTO_EDITAL","VenceMenorOferta":false,"Versao":0,"Chave":8005},"Modalidade":{"Descricao":"Pregão","Chave":1},"TipoLicitacao":{"Descricao":"Pública","SiglaSistemaBbmnet":"LIC","Chave":1},"TipoCotacao":{"Descricao":"Menor Preço","Chave":1},"OrgaoPromotor":{"NomeResumido":"CESAT OrgPub","IsAtivo":false,"Chave":1162},"EtapaLote":{"Descricao":"Não iniciado","Chave":1},"SituacaoLote":{"Descricao":"Em Andamento","Chave":1},"TipoTermino":{"IsRandomico":true,"Chave":1},"Lote":{"QuantidadeCasaDecimal":0,"DataHoraAlteracao":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","OfertasVencedoras":[],"Ofertas":[],"ItensLote":[],"LoteAdendos":[],"NumeroLote":1,"ValorTotalItensLote":0.0,"NumeroRodada":1,"Eventos":[],"DescricaoProduto":"","SomaPrecoProdutos":0.0,"DescricaoSituacaoLote":"","EditalLoteFormatado":"","DescricaoTipoLicitacao":"","DescricaoModalidade":"","NomeOrgaoPromotor":"","DataHoraInicio":"","Objeto":"","Versao":0,"OfertasMPEPP":[],"QuantidadeOfertasAtivas":0,"Chave":8029},"LoteItem":{"QuantidadeProduto":100.00000,"UnidadeProduto":{"DataInclusao":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Chave":0.0},"PrecoProduto":0.0,"PrecoProdutoAtual":0.0,"DataHoraAlteracao":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Numero":0,"CodigoDescricaoProduto":"","PrecoProdutoFormatado":"0,00","Ofertas":[],"Chave":8283},"CodigoUnidade":"Unidade","TempoDecorrido":0,"PrecoReferencia":50000.0000000000000,"PercentualVariacao":0.00,"DataHoraUltimaAlteracao":"2012-08-02T14:33:22","Estado":{"Chave":"AC"},"DivulgacaoPreco":false,"DataHoraUltimoInicio":"2012-08-02T14:50:00","QuantidadeInteressado":0.00000,"DescricaoModalidade":"Pregão Pública Menor Preço","PrecoReferenciaExibicao":50000.0000000000000,"PercentualVariacaoExibicao":0.00,"TempoDecorridoExibicao":1207233,"QuantidadeProdutoExibicao":"100,00000Unidade","SituacaoExibicao":"Não iniciado/Em Andamento","Legendas":[4],"MelhorLanceExibicao":0.0,"Chave":14},{"Edital":{"OpcaoDesclassificacaoRegraDezPorcento":false,"DataInclusaoEdital":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","NumeroEdital":"99902/2012","DescricaoObjeto":"BURGO","DataInicioFase":"2012-08-02T14:50:00","DataHoraUltimaAlteracao":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","InformacaoAtributoPadrao":false,"Lotes":[],"EditalConvidados":[],"EditalAdendos":[],"EditalAnexos":[],"MembrosEquipe":[],"Interessados":[],"Objetivo":"","NomeModalidade":"","NomeModalidaCompleta":"","NomeSituacao":"","NomeOrgaoPromotor":"","NomeUnidadeCompradora":"","ChaveIdentificacaoDocumento":"DOCUMENTO_EDITAL","VenceMenorOferta":false,"Versao":0,"Chave":8005},"Modalidade":{"Descricao":"Pregão","Chave":1},"TipoLicitacao":{"Descricao":"Pública","SiglaSistemaBbmnet":"LIC","Chave":1},"TipoCotacao":{"Descricao":"Menor Preço","Chave":1},"OrgaoPromotor":{"NomeResumido":"CESAT OrgPub","IsAtivo":false,"Chave":1162},"EtapaLote":{"Descricao":"Não iniciado","Chave":1},"SituacaoLote":{"Descricao":"Em Andamento","Chave":1},"TipoTermino":{"IsRandomico":true,"Chave":1},"Lote":{"QuantidadeCasaDecimal":0,"DataHoraAlteracao":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","OfertasVencedoras":[],"Ofertas":[],"ItensLote":[],"LoteAdendos":[],"NumeroLote":2,"ValorTotalItensLote":0.0,"NumeroRodada":1,"Eventos":[],"DescricaoProduto":"","SomaPrecoProdutos":0.0,"DescricaoSituacaoLote":"","EditalLoteFormatado":"","DescricaoTipoLicitacao":"","DescricaoModalidade":"","NomeOrgaoPromotor":"","DataHoraInicio":"","Objeto":"","Versao":0,"OfertasMPEPP":[],"QuantidadeOfertasAtivas":0,"Chave":8030},"LoteItem":{"QuantidadeProduto":50.00000,"UnidadeProduto":{"DataInclusao":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Chave":0.0},"PrecoProduto":0.0,"PrecoProdutoAtual":0.0,"DataHoraAlteracao":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Numero":0,"CodigoDescricaoProduto":"","PrecoProdutoFormatado":"0,00","Ofertas":[],"Chave":8284},"CodigoUnidade":"Caixa","TempoDecorrido":0,"PrecoReferencia":5000.0000000000000,"PercentualVariacao":0.00,"DataHoraUltimaAlteracao":"2012-08-02T14:33:22","Estado":{"Chave":"AC"},"DivulgacaoPreco":false,"DataHoraUltimoInicio":"2012-08-02T14:50:00","QuantidadeInteressado":0.00000,"DescricaoModalidade":"Pregão Pública Menor Preço","PrecoReferenciaExibicao":5000.0000000000000,"PercentualVariacaoExibicao":0.00,"TempoDecorridoExibicao":1207234,"QuantidadeProdutoExibicao":"50,00000Caixa","SituacaoExibicao":"Não iniciado/Em Andamento","Legendas":[4],"MelhorLanceExibicao":0.0,"Chave":15}]}
```